# How to change default cipher in GnuPG on both Linux and Windows?

Tags: windows, linux, gnupg

How can I change the default symmetric cipher used by GnuPG from CAST5 to another?

I'm using GPG4Win on Windows, but would also be interested in a solution for Linux.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If there is no option in the graphical user interface, edit GnuPG's configuration file instead. In the end, graphical user interfaces for GnuPG don't do anything else but calling the GnuPG command line.

### Encrypting to Others

There are two options to set the used algorithms for *encrypting to other people*: `cipher-algo [algorithm]` and `personal-cipher-preferences [algorithm]`. Latter is preferred, as it both takes the other user's algorithm capabilities and preferences into account, and complies to the OpenPGP standard; while `cipher-algo` enforces a given algorithm.

You can look up available algorithms by running `gpg --version`, on Windows you might have to call `gpg.exe --version` and `cd` to the installation directory before. An example output might include:

```
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
```

To enforce the use of `AES256`, edit your `gpg.conf` file and add following line:

```
personal-cipher-preferences AES256
```

### Receiving Encrypted Messages

You can also set preferences which algorithms you want others to choose when they send encrypted messages to you. This might only be available on the command line, but will have affect no matter what client application the other is using (but remember: it is only a proposal of your preferences, and not enforced, compare with `cipher-algo` above).

Start the edit menu using `gpg --edit-key [key-id]` (replacing `[key-id]` with your key id, and you might have to use `gpg.exe` again as described above). Inside, you can use `showpref` to list the currently set up preferences, and `setpref` to change them. The user interface for doing so is *horrible*, and you have to provide a long list of cipher, digest and compression algorithms, while the preferred ones always have to be listed first.

An [article on debian-administration.org](https://debian-administration.org/users/dkg/weblog/48) also describes this procedure, and proposes following preferences, which seem reasonable:

```
setpref SHA512 SHA384 SHA256 SHA224 AES256 AES192 AES CAST5 ZLIB BZIP2 ZIP Uncompressed
```

Comment: The documentation says about gpg.conf but this file is not present in the folder

Comment: It should be in `%APPDATA%\gnupg` (you can copy that path to the Explorer address bar, it will resolve the environment variable).

Comment: I found the file. What I need to insert in that file?

Comment: Exactly what I described. If you want to prefer AES with 256 bit, add a line `personal-cipher-preferences AES256` somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Updated: 
For Gpg4win, I see two options:

- For S/MIME, the GUI has a place to set it (Settings -> Configure Kleopatra -> GnuPG System -> GPG for S/MIME -> Use cipher algorithm)
- Otherwise, you have to alter the underlying gpg.conf file

@jens-erat has already more knowledgeably described the latter, but I will offer the following inputs based on playing with it myself:

1. The command line gpg you're going to use is %INSTALLDIR%\gpg2.exe; on my system that worked out to C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG
2. You can find out your homedir (where you need to put gpg.conf) by running `gpg2 --version` and looking for the line like `Home: C:/Users/gowenfawr/AppData/Roaming/gnupg`

Original (non-GUI) answer:

If you're using the command line gpg, then the **--cipher-algo** argument will allow you to choose your cipher, and you can use **--version** to see which ciphers are available.

(Test shown here on Linux, should be equivalent for Windows)

```
$ gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.16
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: ~/.gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, RSA-E, RSA-S, ELG-E, DSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: MD5, SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
$ file test*
test1.txt: ASCII text
test2.txt: ASCII text
$ gpg --cipher-algo TWOFISH -c test1.txt 
Enter passphrase: 
Repeat passphrase: 
$ gpg --cipher-algo AES256 -c test2.txt 
Enter passphrase: 
Repeat passphrase: 
$ file test*
test1.txt:     ASCII text
test1.txt.gpg: GPG symmetrically encrypted data (TWOFISH cipher)
test2.txt:     ASCII text
test2.txt.gpg: GPG symmetrically encrypted data (AES256 cipher)
$
```

Comment: I am using GUI version of Windows.

Comment: [Gpg4win](http://gpg4win.org/index.html)?

Comment: Yes. I could not find any settings option.